# Datalist in asp.net? ItemCommand event not firing?

Tags: .net, asp.net, datalist

in my web application i have a datalist in that i am binding some images. in datalist itemcommand event i write code some code which is not firing, i mean the itemcomand event is not firing.  can u help me.
this is my source code

DataList control:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DLQuickVideos" runat="server"  RepeatColumns ="2" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" OnItemCommand="DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand" >                       
     <ItemTemplate>                                        
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../Trailorvideos/"+ Eval("SnapShot") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("video")+"|"+Eval("videoid") %>' CausesValidation="false"  Width="111px" Height="83px" BorderStyle="double" BorderWidth="4px" BorderColor="#A70202" />                                                                    
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Event Handler:

```
protected void DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{        
    try
    {
        string eval = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
        int k = eval.IndexOf("|");
        videoname = eval.Substring(0, k);
        videoid = eval.Substring(k + 1);
        string move = Request.QueryString["movie"].ToString();

        if (Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")
        {
            dvplayer.InnerHtml = "<object id='player' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' name='player' width='500' height='350'>      <param name='movie' value='player-viral.swf' />     <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true' />       <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always' />       <param name='flashvars' value='file=~/User/Trailorvideos/" + videoname + "&autostart=true' />   <p><a href='http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer'>Get Flash</a> to see this player.</p>         </object>";
        }
        else
        {
            dvplayer.InnerHtml = "<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='player-viral.swf' width='500' height='350'> <param name='movie' value='player-viral.swf' /> <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true' /> <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always' /> <param name='flashvars' value='file=~/User/Trailorvideos/" + videoname + "&autostart=true' /> <p><a href='http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer'>Get Flash</a> to see this player.</p> </object>";
        }
        GetQuickList(videoid);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

above code .cs code

Comment: Are you binding the event handler to the control? Can you post the relevant code (both code behind and aspx/ascx)?

Comment: source code..........
<asp:DataList ID="DLQuickVideos" runat="server"  RepeatColumns ="2" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" OnItemCommand="DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand" >                       
                                 <ItemTemplate>                                        
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "../Trailorvideos/"+ Eval("SnapShot") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("video")+"|"+Eval("videoid") %

Comment: i place this datalist in a table which is in div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have posted that this is your page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack) //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack 
    { 
        GetQuickList(videoid, moviename); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        GetQuickList(videoid, moviename) 
    } 
}
```

This will not work. You must not databind on post back. Otherwise any pending event handler  requests are cancelled.

You must remove the else part of this if statement.

Comment: so we not bind  when IsPostback is true. Other wise events or not fired

Comment: I mean when we bind data in IsPostback is true then events will not fired am i right Mr. Philip Smith.

Answer (score 5):

When are you binding the DataList?  If the DataList is bound on PageLoad but you are not handling for a PostBack then all attached event handlers will be lost as the DataList is re-bound.  The ItemCommand event will never be raised in this case.

Make sure your Page_Load method is structured as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)  //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack
   {
      //Bind DataList
   }
}
```

The above code will ensure that the DataList is not re-created on PostBack.

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) that covers the Page.IsPostBack property

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)  //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack
   {
       GetQuickList(videoid, moviename);
   }
  else
{
  GetQuickList(videoid, moviename)
}   

}

Comment: Are you able to hit breakpoints placed in DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand?

Answer (score 1):

Add a command name to the button.  I think that is the reason.

HTH.

Comment: ya i tried that one just now it is not entering into that itemcommand event. i write response.write("hai") it is not showing that message Mr.Brain

Comment: Temporarily, try using a Button, and set try it with UseSubmitBehavior="false".

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not databinding the DataList on a postback.  Events are not fired if the control isn't databound.  Can you post the code that does  your databinding, maybe in Page_Load?

Comment: this is my binding code
protected void GetQuickList(string vidid)
    {
       string squery123 = "select * from Trailor_videos where movie='"+movie+"' and Trailor_videos.videoid!=" + vidid;        
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(squery123, con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "temp");
        DLQuickVideos.DataSource = ds.Tables["temp"];
        DLQuickVideos.DataBind();
       
    }

Answer (score 1):

This works:

markup:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DLQuickVideos" runat="server"  RepeatColumns ="2" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" OnItemCommand="DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand" >                       
     <ItemTemplate>                                        
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" runat="server" ImageUrl='xx' CommandArgument='<%# "test" + "|" + Eval("Test") %>' CausesValidation="false"  Width="111px" Height="83px" BorderStyle="double" BorderWidth="4px" BorderColor="#A70202" />                                                                    
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            {
                if (!IsPostBack)  //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("test", typeof(int)));

                    System.Data.DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
                    r["test"] = 1;
                    dt.Rows.Add(r);

                    r = dt.NewRow();
                    r["test"] = 2;
                    dt.Rows.Add(r);

                    this.DLQuickVideos.DataSource = dt;
                    this.DLQuickVideos.DataBind();
                }
            }


        }

        protected void DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

But what i don't understand is you are calling `GetQuickList` in `DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand`. What for? But where do you **initially** fill the DataList?

Comment: yes in page load i am calling the GetQuickList(videoid, moviename)

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (!IsPostBack) //this IF statement is what prevents re-binding on PostBack { GetQuickList(videoid, moviename); } else { GetQuickList(videoid, moviename) } }

Comment: Remove the GetQuickList(videoid); from your DLQuickVideos_ItemCommand !

Comment: Can you paste the html that is rendered in your browser for the DataList?

Comment: This  code.....<table id="DLQuickVideos" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><tr><td><input type="image" name="DLQuickVideos$ctl00$imgbtn" id="DLQuickVideos_ctl00_imgbtn" src="../Trailorvideos/dasava04.flv.jpg" style="border-color:#A70202;border-width:4px;border-style:Double;height:83px;width:111px;" />  
   </td><td>  <input type="image" name="DLQuickVideos$ctl01$imgbtn" id="DLQuickVideos_ctl01_imgbtn" src="../Trailorvideos/dasava06.flv.jpg" style="border-color:#A70202;border-width:4px;border-style:Double;height:83px;width:111px;"/>